# Conditional rbind elements between 2 lists if their names() match; Map()?

Tags: r, dictionary, conditional-statements, rbind

I have 2 lists of objects that I want to rbind:

```
BothJoined <- Map(rbind, A, B)
```

However, I want to find a way to conditionally rbind, where rbind happens on all list elements with matching `names()`

Example:

```
A <- list("a" = as.data.frame(50:55), "b" = as.data.frame(5:10),  "c" = as.data.frame(1:3))
colnames(A$a) <- "Col"
colnames(A$b) <- "Col"
colnames(A$c) <- "Col"

B <- list("a" = as.data.frame(55:60),  "c" = as.data.frame(4:6))
colnames(B$a) <- "Col"
colnames(B$c) <- "Col"
```

How a solution would look:

```
BothJoined <- MapOnMatchingNames(A,B)

BothJoined$a
   Col
1   50
2   51
3   52
4   53
5   54
6   55
7   55
8   56
9   57
10  58
11  59
12  60

BothJoined$b
   Col
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
5   9
6   10

BothJoined$c
   Col
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
```

Ideally, method/function work regardless of the `typeof()` object being stored in each list element.

Comment: `Map(rbind, A, B[names(A)])`?

Comment: actually not bad. yea... That should even work when the elements in the lists are not ordered in the same order.
Simple answer.

Comment: @MikaelJagan if you just copy pasted that into an answer I can mark your answer as right. if you want. sorry.

Comment: OK - I've added an answer. It's no trouble at all.

Comment: Sorry just say your answer, but also came up with an exception I am not sure has an simple solution: when B has `names()` not contained in A , those would be lost.

Comment: Fixed now, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite efficiently with

```r
nms <- union(names(A), names(B))
l <- Map(rbind, A[nms], B[nms])
names(l) <- nms # needed if 'names(A)' does not contain 'names(B)'
```